# local variable referenced before assignment (CounterOne)

Tags: python, variables, indentation

I ran the code before adding the `CounterOne` variable and it ran fine.

But after adding the `CounterOne` variable the compiler starts giving me below error.

> "local variable 'CounterOne' referenced before assignment"

```
CounterOne = 0.00

def AAPILoad():
    return 0

def AAPIInit():
    return 0

def AAPIManage(time, timeSta, timeTrans, acycle):
    AKIPrintString( "AAPIManage" )      

    xy = doSomething() #Read Number of Sections
    for i in range (xy):
        id = getID(i) #Read the identifier of a section
        if (id==331):
            xyz = DoCal(id,True) #Read the number of vehicles in a section
            for j in range (xyz):
                Calculaitons

                if (0<=distanceFromTrafficLight<=300):
                    if ( condition == False) :
                        do calculations
                    else :
                        print ("Condition failed")

                    if ( Condition):  #Cruising 
                        Calval = 0.233+2*someValue

                        CounterOne = CounterOne + Calval
    return 0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CounterOne
```

Is not a global variable, that is why the error is thrown.

You can either make it global, which is not `recommended`, or pass the `CounterOne` value to the function.

**For global method:**

```
def AAPIManage(time, timeSta, timeTrans, acycle):
    global CounterOne
   AKIPrintString( "AAPIManage" )
```

**For function method :**

```
def AAPIManage(time, timeSta, timeTrans, acycle,CounterOne):
```

**AND RETURN CounterOne instead of zero**

Comment: I already tried making the variable global which resulted in getting the same error again. Could you explain more on passing the value to the function. I need the counter to update the assigned value each time the code is running